# Как реализовать svg компонент в react + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В React на JS я подключал svg в качестве компонента вот таким путем

```
import { ReactLogoComponent } from "./churros.svg";
```

И использовал в компонентах вот так

```
<ReactLogoComponent
      width={50}
      height={50}
      className={s.logo__img}
    />
```

То есть из файла получался реакт компонент
Пробую перевести этот код на react с typescrypt.
Обычные **import** не работает использую **require**
Подключаю:

```
const ReactLogoComponent: FC<SVGAttributes<SVGElement>> = require("./churros.svg");
```

Использую так:

```
<ReactLogoComponent
          width={"50"}
          height={"50"}
          className={s.logo__img}
 />
```

в консоле при сборке ошибок нет, но в браузере ошибка:

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
> 'Document': The tag name provided
> ('/static/media/churros.88138d03.svg') is not a valid name.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать правильно этот момент? Проект на **CRA**, перевожу с **JS** на **TS**

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, что модуль **.svg*  описан в react-scripts(node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d) и по именованному экспорту возвращает ReactComponent, по этому:

```
import { ReactComponent as ReactLogoComponent } from "./churros.svg";
```

Но в моем случае это не полностью решило проблему, потому что TS начал ругаться на то, что он не может найти **модуль** churros.svg или **объявление соответствующего типа** - это решилось добавлением в src/ файла **react-app-env.d.ts**
с содержимым

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```